# Finding the density function from joint density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm reading the conditional distributions section of Probability and Random Processes by Grimmett and Stirzaker and I've come across a brief exercise I can't seem to figure out.

We're given earlier that $f_{X}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy$ and the example states that X and Y have joint density function

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1$

And then it says: show for yourself (exercise) that $f_{X}(x)=1$ if $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

I think I must be being stupid, but I keep getting:

$f_{X}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dy=\left [ \frac{y}{x} \right ]_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{x}$. Why is this wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to "integrate out" $y$. Note that the joint density is $\frac{1}{x}$ in the part of the unit square **below** the line $y=x$. So we integrate the constant $\frac{1}{x}$ from $y=0$ to $y=x$. **Not** from $y=0$ to $y=1$. Above the line $y=x$, we have $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Probability is the field where one meets most often functions defined by different formulas in different parts of the world. First thing I did when looking at the problem was to draw a picture.